# Is it possible to copy y value at cursor from a Matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say my cursor is at a y value of 1 on the figure, is there any way to add this value to my clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer from a human :-D

I think what you ultimately want is to attach a callback...

(see https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html)

Here's for example how you can print the current position of the cursor (in data-coordinates) to the console if you move the mouse:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots()

def get_curser_pos(event):
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        xy = event.x, event.y
        
        print("the mouse position is:",
              ax.transData.inverted().transform(xy))
    
    
f.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", get_curser_pos)
```